# Read Excel Formulas

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I need to get all the excel formulas from the worksheet.I am using Range.SpecialCells and iterating through the each cell to get formula and it is really slow.Is there any better solution to get only formulas as list of strings?

Sample code:

```
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
Range range = worksheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas);
foreach(Cell cell in range.Cells)
{
   string formula = cell.formula.ToString();
   //some code
}
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service please provide a specific problem with a
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MattRowland updated with code.

Comment: I don't see any reason why it should be slow.  Are you sure that the problem  is with the snippet you provided?

Comment: @RayFischer I am searching for certain strings in the formulas and I have  worksheets with lot of formulas( > 30k).there is one method get_value to get values and it is faster.Is there any method for formulas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the **range.formula** property.

For example:

> In cell A3, the cell formula is '=DATE(D3,C3,1)'
>
> In cell B3, the cell formula is '=A3'

With the code:

```
Range r = activeWorksheet.get_Range("A3","B3");
var c = r.Formula;
```

The variable c will contain sort of like a list of the cells specified in that range and their respective formula.

> Output of C:
>
> [1,1] = "=DATE(D3,C3,1)"
>
> [1,2] = "=A3"

Answer (score 0):

This is a totally different way to do it, but it might help you,

Just press CRTL + ` (backquote), this will make all the formula visible in the excel sheet. You could then search what you want or copy paste in a txt file to make searches and modifications.

If you are just searching for some strings within a formula, you can use `CTRL + F` , select look in formulas and search the strings